# Issues with Adding `subxt` Dependency to `node-template-runtime` in Substrate Project

Tags: substrate-node-template, subxt

I'm developing a project based on the `substrate-node-template` and encountered an issue when adding a `subxt` dependency. When I add `subxt = { version = "0.29", default-features = false }` to the Cargo.toml of the `node-template` module, everything works fine. Here is a part of the Cargo.toml from the `node-template` module:

```
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[[bin]]
name = "node-template"

[dependencies]
subxt = { version = "0.29", default-features = false }

[build-dependencies]
substrate-build-script-utils.workspace = true

[features]
default = []
```

However, adding the same dependency to the `node-template-runtime` module's Cargo.toml leads to an error. Here is a part of the Cargo.toml from the `node-template-runtime` module:

```
[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
subxt = { version = "0.29", default-features = false }

[build-dependencies]
substrate-wasm-builder = { version = "5.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", optional = true , branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
```

The error message I receive is:

```
error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`
note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `tracing` depends on)
note: second definition in the local crate (`sp_io`)
error: could not compile `sp-io` (lib) due to 1 previous error
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does adding this dependency to the `node-template-runtime` module cause an error?
2. I've heard that all dependencies in `node-template-runtime` must be `no_std`, but why then does the Cargo.toml of the `node-template-runtime` module have `default = ["std"]` in its features?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does adding this dependency to the node-template-runtime module cause an error?

The runtime must support compiling the code to no-std and subxt doesn't support that yet. There are ongoing work to make parts of subxt to be no-std though. That's why you get the error `found duplicate lang item` panic_impl`

> I've heard that all dependencies in node-template-runtime must be no_std, but why then does the Cargo.toml of the node-template-runtime module have default = ["std"] in its features?

The std feature is only enabled when the runtime is compiled to native and that's those std features exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add subxt to your chain build, subxt is designed to connect to your chain using rpc. Create a tool to submit extrinsics and read state from the chain like polkadot-js does but from rust code.